# Why ido mode automatically change current folder when create new file?

Tags: ido

I want to create file `credenentials.txt` in folder `d:/dev/GoogleDrive/_IPTV/Playlists/OttClub/`

```
M-x C-x C-f
```

[image]

Press "**c**"
result:

[image]

press "**cr**"
result:

[image]

As you can see Emacs change folder to `d:/personal`

I don't need this.
I only want to create file in folder `d:/dev/GoogleDrive/_IPTV/Playlists/OttClub/`

How I can do this?

P.S.
I also try by `-Q` mode and enable only `ido-mode`
I get same result:
[image]
Press "**cr**"
[image]

As you can see Emacs **automatically change** folder.

Comment: It seems to be not the ususal ido behaviour. Can you reproduce it with emacs -Q and ido-mode enabled?

Comment: @andrej I updated my post. Not help. Same result

Comment: Don't know what is going on! Seems to be a bug to me. Maybe try updating emacs? As a workaround you can press C-f (after C-x C-f) to fall back to the usual find-file

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17986194/emacs-disable-automatic-file-search-in-ido-mode) what you're looking for? Either set `ido-auto-merge-work-directories-length` to a negative value, or increase the number of seconds in `ido-auto-merge-delay-time`.

Comment: @jagrg ido-auto-merge-delay-time - this help. Thanks

Comment: @jagrg nice! Consider turning your comment into an answer, so that the question can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should either set `ido-auto-merge-work-directories-length` to a negative value, or increase the number of seconds in `ido-auto-merge-delay-time`.

Answer (score 2):

It's also possible to pause Ido completion by typing `C-f` at the Ido prompt as soon as you have the correct directory, and then type the new file name:

`C-x C-f` navigate to directory `C-f` type new file name `RET`

You can also list the key bindings available during the Ido file prompt by typing the following (either during and Ido prompt or outside):

`C-h f` ido-find-file `RET`